# .htaccess Regexp start with or

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have declare Rewrite rule if url start with `'katalogas/imone'` or `'imone'` I try that:

```
RewriteRule ^(katalogas/imone|imone)/(.*) http://google.lt
```

In statment `(katalogas/imone|imone)` is something wrong, because `'/'` means that 2 argument is not important, how to escape `'/'`. I mean it must start `'katalogas/imone'` or `'imone'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your regular expression. The only optimization could be to refactor the two prefixes into one with an optional part

```
RewriteRule ^((?:katalogas/)?imone)/(.*) http://google.lt
```

and since you don't use the captured parts, you can further simplify it to

```
RewriteRule ^(?:katalogas/)?imone/ http://google.lt
```

Another approach could be to just use two separate rules

```
RewriteRule ^katalogas/imone/ http://google.lt
RewriteRule ^imone/ http://google.lt
```